# Rendering Collection of collections - ItemsControl

Tags: wpf

I have an object model like below:

```
public class ViewModel
{
 public List<Group> Groups{ get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsOnline { get; set; }
}
```

and I'm binding the groups to an itemscontrol like this:

```
  <ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Groups}"
       ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GroupTemplate}" >
    </ItemsControl>
```

and I have datatemplate for rendering them.

```
       <DataTemplate x:Key="GroupTemplate" DataType="{x:Type Group}">
       </DataTemplate>
 <DataTemplate x:Key="ContactTemplate" DataType="{x:Type Contact}">
<StackPanel>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
</StackPanle>
       </DataTemplate>
```

How can I get the contacts displayed inside the items control? The contacts is a collection inside each group and my viewmodel has a collection of groups. To complicate it a bit further, I have different datatemplates for different contacts, and I should be using a datatemplateselector for choosing the appropriate contact template. Also please note, I have nothing to display in the group template, and I only need to show Contacts.

Thanks,
-Mike

Comment: Hi, I have similar kind of issue but I'm unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another ItemsControl in the first template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GroupTemplate" DataType="{x:Type my:Group}">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:Contact}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

And with a template selector:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GroupTemplate" DataType="{x:Type my:Group}">
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}"
                ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource yourContactItemSelector}"/>
 </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Hi, I have similar kind of issue but I'm unable to figure it out.

Comment: simmilar ques: help wiull be appriciated
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24445571/grid-view-or-listview-binding-or-rendering-of-collection-of-collection