# Grid View or ListView Binding or Rendering of Collection of Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

**A complete new bee in XAML and WPF shifted from MVC 1 week back**

**Requirement:**

Display Customer Name and all corresponding Brands

1 Customer can have Many Brands

**Issue**

Unable to display the corresponding brands

**Reference**

[Similar SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524071/rendering-collection-of-collections-itemscontrol)

**Code**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = new MyDeviceList();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class MyDeviceList
{
    Entities ent = new Entities();
    public ObservableCollection<myCustomers> Customers { get; set; }

    public void GetCustomersBrand()
    {
        var custall = (from c in ent.Customers
                    select new myCustomers{ name = c.Name, brands = c.Brands.ToList() }).ToList();

        Customers = new ObservableCollection<myCustomers>(custall);

    }

    public MyDeviceList()
    {
        GetCustomersBrand();
    }
}

//just a dummy class
public class Brand
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Customerid { get; set; }
}


public class myCustomers
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Brand> brands { get; set; }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="DeviceListCreate.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:DeviceListCreate"
    Title="MainWindow" WindowState="Maximized">

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="GroupTemplate" DataType="{x:Type my:myCustomers}">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding brands}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" Name="tStack" Grid.Column="0" Margin="33,10,42,10">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"/>                      
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Kindly guide which direction I should be heading now

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should use grouping in your itemscontrol http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/

Comment: @nit thanks nit I think I need something like that
will looking into it

Comment: edited my question, well but actually my problem is how to bind/call the DataTemplate 'GroupTemplate' inside my `<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>` @strattonn

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee a much easier solution is to have an ItemsControl 
where each item template for Customer is a panel with TextBlock for the name and another ItemControl with Brands Bound as it's ItemsSource

Comment: @eranotzap well thats what exactly im trying and want to do, but unable to bound the Brands :(
so I tried to write another ItemControl inside Data template you can see that in resorce, that gives the brands but im not exactly bound the brand to customer

Comment: @nit i was able to implement the example you gave me, but that's works fine when most of my customers have multiple brands but in my case just 2 cutomers have multiple brand rest all have 1 brand so I will not look good.

secondly the customers are also horizontally alligned as you can see in the screen shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When constructing a UI like this, you just have to build it up part by part. Concentrating on each part individually makes the whole task more manageable. Try this:

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="RoyalBlue" BorderThickness="1" 
                    Padding="5" Margin="5">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Margin="5" />
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding brands}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding name}" Margin="5" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply but its still not showing the Brand name :(

Comment: Thanks its working I was unable to bind the Brands to the Customers
instead of `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding brands}">`
i was doing `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:myCustomers}">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding brands}">`

Where as I don't need to refer my Class once I'm inside it Thanks alot again
:)

Comment: I've updated the name of your `brands` property now... but please note that this is what happens when you don't use the proper and expected casing on your property names.

Comment: actually I created the Brand class for just dummy :)
and committed the mistake